# Javascript IIFE , Objects

Tags: javascript, object, reference

Please give me some link to help me understand this

```
    var obj = {
  a: 1
};
(function(obj) {
  obj = {
    a: 2
  };
})(obj);
console.log(obj.a);
```

logs out 1 whereas this

```
var obj = {
  a: 1
};
(function() {
  obj = {
    a: 2
  };
})();
console.log(obj.a);
```

logs out 2

Comment: This `function(obj)` is hiding the global variable `obj`

Comment: Link?  http://www.google.com

Answer (score -3):

It is because in example 1 you are creating a new name `obj` as a parameter and it's getting overridden instead of using the passed in value. In example 2, `obj` is being closed around and replaced.